# How to speed up missing search process in a R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am writing a general function for missing value treatment. Data can have Char,numeric,factor and integer type columns. An example of data is as follows

```
dt<-data.table(
  num1=c(1,2,3,4,NA,5,NA,6),
  num3=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
  int1=as.integer(c(NA,NA,102,105,NA,300,400,700)),
  int3=as.integer(c(1,10,102,105,200,300,400,700)),
  cha1=c('a','b','c',NA,NA,'c','d','e'),
  cha3=c('xcda','b','c','miss','no','c','dfg','e'),
  fact1=c('a','b','c',NA,NA,'c','d','e'),
  fact3=c('ad','bd','cc','zz','yy','cc','dd','ed'),
  allm=as.integer(c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)),
  miss=as.character(c("","",'c','miss','no','c','dfg','e')),
  miss2=as.integer(c('','',3,4,5,6,7,8)),
  miss3=as.factor(c(".",".",".","c","d","e","f","g")),
  miss4=as.factor(c(NA,NA,'.','.','','','t1','t2')),
  miss5=as.character(c(NA,NA,'.','.','','','t1','t2'))  
)
```

I was using this code to flag out missing values:

```
dt[,flag:=ifelse(is.na(miss5)|!nzchar(miss5),1,0)]
```

But it turns out to be very slow, additionally I have to add logic which could also consider "." as missing.
 So I am planning to write this for missing value identification

```
dt[miss5 %in% c(NA,'','.'),flag:=1]
```

but on a 6 million record set it takes close to 1 second to run this whereas

```
dt[!nzchar(miss5),flag:=1]  takes close 0.14 secod to run.
```

My question is, can we have a code where the time taken is as least as possible while we can look for values NA,blank and Dot(NA,".","") as missing?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81285/discussion-on-question-by-anuj-how-to-speed-up-missing-search-process-in-a-r-dat).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`==` and `%in%` are optimised to use binary search automatically (NEW FEATURE: Auto indexing). To use it, we have to ensure that:

a) we use `dt[...]` instead of `set()` as it's not yet implemented in `set()`, [#1196](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1196).

b) When RHS to `%in%` is of higher SEXPTYPE than LHS, auto indexing re-routes to base R to ensure correct results (as binary search always coerces RHS). So for integer columns we need to make sure we pass in just `NA` and not the `"."` or `""`.

Using @akrun's data, here's the code and run time:

```
in_col = grep("^miss", names(dt), value=TRUE)
out_col = gsub("^miss", "flag", in_col)
system.time({
    dt[, (out_col) := 0L]
    for (j in seq_along(in_col)) {
        if (class(.subset2(dt, in_col[j])) %in% c("character", "factor")) {
            lookup = c("", ".", NA)
        } else lookup = NA
        expr = call("%in%", as.name(in_col[j]), lookup)
        tt = dt[eval(expr), (out_col[j]) := 1L]
    }
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   1.174   0.295   1.476
```

How it works:

a) we first initiate all output columns to 0.

b) Then, for each column, we check it's type and create `lookup` accordingly.

c) We then create the corresponding expression for `i` - `miss(.) %in% lookup`

d) Then we evaluate the expression in `i`, which'll use *auto indexing* to create an index very quickly and use that index to quickly find matching indices using *binary search*.

> Note: If necessary, you can add a `set2key(dt, NULL)` at the end of for-loop so that the created indices are removed immediately after use (to save space).

Compared to this run, @akrun's fastest answer takes *6.33 seconds*, which is ~4.2x speedup.

**Update:** On 4 million rows and 100 columns, it takes ~ 9.2 seconds. That's ~0.092 seconds per column.

Calling `[.data.table` a 100 times could be expensive. When auto indexing is implemented in `set()`, it'd be nice to compare the performance.

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through the 'miss' columns and create corresponding 'flag' columns with `set`.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
ind <- grep('^miss', names(dt))
nm1 <- sub('miss', 'flag',names(dt)[ind])
dt[,(nm1) := 0]
for(j in seq_along(ind)){
     set(dt, i=which(dt[[ind[j]]] %in% c('.', '', NA)),j= nm1[j], value=1L)
  }
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA,0:9), 6e6*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
set.seed(23)
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c('.','', letters[1:5]), 6e6*5,
   replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
set.seed(234)
i1 <- sample(10)
dfN <- setNames(cbind(df1, df2)[i1], paste0('miss',1:10))
dt <- as.data.table(dfN)

system.time({
 ind <- grep('^miss', names(dt))
 nm1 <- sub('miss', 'flag',names(dt)[ind])
 dt[,(nm1) := 0L]
 for(j in seq_along(ind)){
  set(dt, i=which(dt[[ind[j]]] %in% c('.', '', NA)), j= nm1[j], value=1L)
  }
 }
)
#user  system elapsed 
#  8.352   0.150   8.496 

system.time({
 m1 <- matrix(0, nrow=6e6, ncol=10)
 m2 <- sapply(seq_along(dt), function(i) {
   ind <- which(dt[[i]] %in% c('.', '', NA))
    replace(m1[,i], ind, 1L)})
  cbind(dt, m2)})
 #user  system elapsed 
 # 14.227   0.362  14.582
```